# How to import a GUI into a python script

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to import a script with a simple GUI into my main python script and get this error by executing test.py:

> TypeError: **init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'root'

Main script: test.py

```
import input_1

print('before window')
input_1.App()
print('after window')
```

GUI script: input_1.py

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font as tkFont
    
class App:
    def __init__(self, root):
        #setting title
        root.title("Input stator batch and number")
        #setting window size
        width=456

        ...

    def GButton_293_command(self):
        print("command")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = App(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

**Questions:**

1. What do I do wrong? Is there something horribly wrong with my syntax?
2. How do I link the GUI-Script to my main script, when it is located in different folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your test.py script, you need to define the inputs for your App class.

Try this:

```
import input_1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = input_1.App(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Great thank you very much! Can you also help me with my second question?

Comment: The same way, you import it and run it in your main script, supplying root as input for input_1.App. Not sure what exactly you are looking for